# Rails - How to count how many incomplete orders. .count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created an application where an admin can see a list of incomplete orders (complete: 'f'). I want a small notification to show the user on the dashboard how many orders of his are incomplete. In the controller, on the admin page, I grab the data with:

```
@orders = Order.where(complete: 'f', OrderFini: 't', Storeid: current_user.id).order(:created_at)
```

I think it might be something to do with the .count function but I am unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define `@incomplete_orders_count` in the controller and directly use it in view -

Controller -

```
@incomplete_orders_count = Order.where(complete: 'f', OrderFini: 't', Storeid: current_user.id).count
```

View -

```
<%= @incomplete_orders_count %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct.
You have found orders collection in `@orders` variable.
On view you can simply call following

```
# For ERB
<%= @orders.count %>
```

```
# For HAML
= @orders.count
```